# Difference between userId and Meteor.userId() in allow/deny rules

Tags: meteor

I have a collection and some allow rules on it:

```
Teams = new Meteor.Collection("teams")
Teams.allow({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        console.log(userId);
        console.log(Meteor.userId());
        // do some stuff
    }
})
```

When I do `Teams.insert({ name: "superheroes" })` i see 2 equal strings in console.
So, what the difference between `userId` and `Meteor.userId()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Meteor.userId()` means the user which is currently logged in. `userId` inside of an allow/deny rule means the user that initiated the action. Since you can't make a method call as another user, I can't imagine a situation where these would ever be different. Checking the `userId` in an allow/deny rule is really common, so I assume it was added as an argument just for convenience.