# collection.allow() insert/update/remove redundant userId argument

Tags: meteor

In Meteor for collection.allow() insert callback is "insert(userId, doc) {}" Here isn't the userId argument redundant? Because we can always check it with Meteor.userId(). Why is it being passed as an argument?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is currently unnecessary. I answered a related question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581536/difference-between-userid-and-meteor-userid-in-allow-deny-rules/).

I'd have to ask a core dev why it's there, but if I had to guess it's probably some mix of:

1. It may make unit testing easier.
2. You probably want it anyway, and it's fewer characters to type than `Meteor.userId()`.
3. API baggage - maybe it made a lot of sense when it was added, but removing it would break a lot of code so why bother in light of (1) and (2)?

Comment: 3rd reason sounds highly probable which is what I am guessing too. thanks.